# Is it appropriate to overload Perl's file input angle operator as a general iterator/generator?

Tags: perl, syntax, iterator, generator

I have seen several modules (example: [Iterator::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~rintaro/Iterator-Simple/lib/Iterator/Simple.pm)) that make use of Perl's angle operator as an approximate equivalent to Python generators. Specifically, providing the ability to iterate over a list of values without actually loading the whole list in memory. Is this generally considered to be an appropriate extension of the functionality of the operator, or is it considered to be an abuse of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<HANDLE>` operator is just syntactic sugar for the `readline HANDLE` function, which is very much an iterator over the handle.  If an object provides iterative access, I don't see any problem with overloading `<>` to provide flexibility to the end user.

The `<>` operator does not approximate the generator, the module does that.  All that

```
while (<$iterator>) {...}
```

gives you is a fancy way to write

```
while (defined ($_ = $iterator->next)) {...}
```

Perl is a very expressive language due to the many different ways it allows you to solve problems.  Many modules choose to offer alternative interfaces in this spirit.  This allows users to code the way that works best for them.

Comment: This does not work, because overloaded operator `<>` is only called once!

Comment: @Jakob => not sure what you are talking about, in a `while (<$itr>) {...}` construct, the overloaded operator is called on each loop iteration.

Comment: Sorry, I am wrong: `<>` in a while loop works, but you cannot do `my @all = <$iterator>` or `foreach (<$iterator>)`, so I would not recommend to overload it unless you point out this pitfalls.